# What is meant by, and where do I find "the documentation"?

Tags: documentation

I am new to programming, and often in looking for solutions to questions people will often recommend that question-askers "read the documentation".

By documentation are people referring to sites that describe use cases for various functions and uses of a specific language? (Ex. w3schools, devdocs)

Or is this something released by the creators of the specific programming language?

When I have tried looking up "the documentation" of specific languages I am usually presented with "documentation" as it refers to using comments to ensure that your code is readable for the next developer.
Specifically I am looking for something that goes more in depth into CSS (than w3schools) so I can develop a deeper understanding of it.

Comment: W3schools has a almost complete CSS, Javascript, HTML information for beginners. If you already know all that stuff, then you should know where to find sites like php.net. If you need the basics, stay at w3schools, or search youtube for  the hundreds of thousands of videos created by coders

Comment: Often, the answers or comments suggesting documentation will link to the particular section they have in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programming languages, software, web applications etc. normally have some kind of user manual or „how-to“-instructions.

Example: https://docs.python.org/3/

This is the actual documentation of the latest Python release.

You‘ll find the documentations - or a link to it - mostly on the homepage of a products or services website.